# apply np.sign to pyspark series not working even using udf

Tags: pyspark

I am currently trying to convert all the row values to certain sign by using numpy built-in function np.sign

My code:

```
import numpy as np
pd_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id': [i for i in range(10)],
                             'values': [10,5,3,-1,0,-10,-4,10,0,10]})

sp_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(pd_dataframe)
sign_acc_row = F.udf(lambda x: np.sign([x]), IntegerType())
sp_dataframe = sp_dataframe.withColumn('sign', sign_acc_row('values'))
sp_dataframe.show()
```

Errors:

```
y4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2586.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 320.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 320.0 (TID 3199, localhost, executor driver): net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)
```

Expected output:

```
    id  values  sign
0   0   10  1
1   1   5   1
2   2   3   1
3   3   -1  -1
4   4   0   0
5   5   -10 -1
6   6   -4  -1
7   7   10  1
8   8   0   0
9   9   10  1
```

Side question if allowed:

I wanted to create another column with which it returns an additional of 1 when the value is different from previous row.

Expected output:

```
    id  values  sign    numbering
0   0   10  1   1
1   1   5   1   1
2   2   3   1   1
3   3   -1  -1  2
4   4   0   0   3
5   5   -10 -1  4
6   6   -4  -1  4
7   7   10  1   5
8   8   0   0   6
9   9   10  1   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. `np.sign` return an `numpy.int64` object which is not understood by pyspark. To make them compatiable, you can do:

```
sign_acc_row = F.udf(lambda x: int(np.sign(x)), IntegerType())
```

Comment: wow. There is a lot for me to learn and thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: by the way do you know how I can make it with increasing number. example: 111-101110-1 will be return 1112344456? It means after it change to another different value, an increase of one. Easy explain is 1(1)->-1(2) ->0(3) ->0(3, still 3 because its the same) -> 1(4, because its differnt)

Comment: Didn't understood, could you edit your question with this and expected output.

Comment: Interesting question, looks like haven't been answered before, would you be kind enough to make a new question for this so others can also benefit.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59802617/create-another-columns-for-checking-different-value-in-pyspark

Comment: here. please check