# create another columns for checking different value in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I wish to have below expected output:

My code:

```
import numpy as np
pd_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'id': [i for i in range(10)],
                             'values': [10,5,3,-1,0,-10,-4,10,0,10]})

sp_dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(pd_dataframe)
sign_acc_row = F.udf(lambda x: int(np.sign(x)), IntegerType())
sp_dataframe = sp_dataframe.withColumn('sign', sign_acc_row('values'))
sp_dataframe.show()
```

I wanted to create another column with which it returns an additional of 1 when the value is different from previous row.

Expected output:

```
    id  values  sign    numbering
0   0   10  1   1
1   1   5   1   1
2   2   3   1   1
3   3   -1  -1  2
4   4   0   0   3
5   5   -10 -1  4
6   6   -4  -1  4
7   7   10  1   5
8   8   0   0   6
9   9   10  1   7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way you can do using a custom function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

# compare the next value with previous
def f(x):
    c = 1
    l = [c]
    last_value = [x[0]]
    for i in x[1:]:
        if i == last_value[-1]:
            l.append(c)
        else:
            c += 1
            l.append(c)
        last_value.append(i)
    return l

# take sign column as a list
sign_list = sp_dataframe.select('sign').rdd.map(lambda x: x.sign).collect()

# create a new dataframe using the output
sp = spark.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame(f(sign_list), columns=['numbering']))
```

Append a list as a column to a dataframe is a bit tricky in pyspark. For this we'll need to create a dummy `row_idx` to join the dataframes.

```
# create dummy indexes
sp_dataframe = sp_dataframe.withColumn("row_idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id())
sp = sp.withColumn("row_idx", F.monotonically_increasing_id())

# join the dataframes
final_df = (sp_dataframe
            .join(sp, sp_dataframe.row_idx == sp.row_idx)
            .orderBy('id')
            .drop("row_idx"))

final_df.show()

+---+------+----+---------+
| id|values|sign|numbering|
+---+------+----+---------+
|  0|    10|   1|        1|
|  1|     5|   1|        1|
|  2|     3|   1|        1|
|  3|    -1|  -1|        2|
|  4|     0|   0|        3|
|  5|   -10|  -1|        4|
|  6|    -4|  -1|        4|
|  7|    10|   1|        5|
|  8|     0|   0|        6|
|  9|    10|   1|        7|
+---+------+----+---------+
```

Comment: thank you. I will mark it as answer after reviewing and understand it.

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little of why we need to create dummy row_idx?

Comment: because we want to append the new column vertically to `sp_dataframe`, to do that, we made indexes (or keys) in both the dataframe so that we can join using those keys, it is similar to creating a new `id` column in `sp` dataframe and join on that instead.

Comment: so the 'row_idx' acts as the index and the code 'sp_dataframe.row_idx == sp.row_idx'  is used for this purpose, right? Since you drop it at last, so we left only the numbering column in 'sp', right? I am curious, cant we just use the F.udf and assign the function directly? like ---increasing_number = F.udf(lambda x: int(f(x)), IntegerType())---sp_dataframe = sp_dataframe.withColumn("numbering", increasing_number('sign'))---

Comment: that was my first try, but turns out udf function takes each value of a column as an input, not the entire column at once, in your case, the input to the function is a `list`, udf would take `integer` (each value from `sign` col ) as an input

Comment: Yea, I noticed that as well and do you know whether is there a way to take the whole column instead with the use of udf? Your current method works but somehow, the function 'f' is kind of hard to understand(I understand the others but wondering whether are there any simple method)? If there isnt any other, I will mark this as answer. Its been a great help, thank you.

Comment: I couldn't find any readymade function in pyspark which could do this, it's a quite customised use case, not really made for spark.

Comment: I see. Thank you so much sir for the explanations. I will mark it as answer. thank you for your help